# How remove background from Angular Material Tree

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I've tried to remove the background of my material tree but nothing seems to actually be working.

I want to maintain the background image, the background image is from the `mat-sidenav-container` the `library.component` is rendered on the `mat-sidenav-content`.

[image]

###### library.component.scss

```css
mat-tree-node {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to `style.css` should work.

```css
.mat-tree {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this...it's may working fine

```
  .mat-tree {
      background: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the background-color in a specific component, can add it to the component css instead overwrite the mat-tree background-color for all the project.

```
::ng-deep .mat-tree {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```